# Is it possible to remove lock from a file locked through root

Tags: directory

So I barely began to explore and learn command line, I found that if I download files while in root access the files are automatically locked.  My question is if there is a way to remove the lock to make it more easily accessible and without having to be in root or using the nautilus command, help will be very much appreciated, thank you.

btw: running on Ubuntu 12.xx

Comment: while I am trying to change th owner of the file it's showing like this chown sravan:users aircrack-ng-1.1
chown: changing ownership of `aircrack-ng-1.1': Operation not permitted
what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this from the terminal. When you download a file as root, it is owned by root and default permissions do not allow others to view or modify it. To give you access, you will need to change the owner to the user you want to have access. Assuming your username is brayan and the file is myfile.txt, you would use this command:

```
sudo chown brayan:brayan myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of approach, you can change de permission of the file or change your owner.

```
chmod ugo+rw myfile.txt
```

http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/~dicke3/nerspcs/chmod.html

Or you can chagen the owner. Let's pretender your user is `rachel`, then type:

```
chown rachel:users myfile.txt
```

http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/~dicke3/nerspcs/chown.html